# javascript toggle menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html menu with a button to open it and a unordered list :

```
 <nav class="menu">
        <button>
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </button>

        <ul class="mylist">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Services</li>
        </ul>
        
    </nav>
```

I want to use javascript to alter the ul class to change its margin on click:
CSS:

```
.mylist{
    margin: 300em;
}

.mylist.shown{
    margin: 2em;
}
```

This script doesn't function, can someone point out my problem, thank you

```
let hiddenList= document.querySelector('.mylist');
let button= document.querySelector('button');
hiddenList.style.margin= '300em';



button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    hiddenList.classList.toggle('shown')
})
```

Comment: Don't set the style in JavaScript (remove `hiddenList.style.margin= '300em';`). That is taking precedence over the margin in your style sheet.

Comment: Further to Heretic Monkey's comment, the reason it's taking precedence over the margin in your style-sheet is because `hiddenList.style.margin` writes the property and value to the `style` attribute of the `hiddenList` element; instead: consider using classes to modify the presentation of an element.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set `margin` with the line:

```
hiddenList.style.margin= '300em';
```

since you already define the element with that margin in the CSS with:

```css
.mylist{
    margin: 300em;
}
```

So just remove that.

The reason that was causing a problem is that the line of script was the equivalent of adding the following to the HTML:

```html
<ul class="mylist" style="margin: 300em">
```

And with the rules of precedence in CSS being what they are, that inline style has a higher priority over that declared in the CSS.

See [MDN's article on CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you fixed inline style by this line:

```
hiddenList.style.margin= '300em';
```

Then just remove it then everything works

```js
let hiddenList= document.querySelector('.mylist');
let button= document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(hiddenList)
    hiddenList.classList.toggle('shown')
})
```

```css
.mylist{
    margin: 300em;
}

.mylist.shown{
    margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
        <button>
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </button>

        <ul class="mylist">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Services</li>
        </ul>
        
    </nav>
```